# How did "at once" get to be used to mean "immediately"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

How did "at once" become an idiom meaning "do this immediately" or "as soon as possible"?

I just thought of this question after seeing this old UK WWI Propaganda poster in the link below. I glanced over it, and thought it seemed a bit awkward to be used in this way. Which made me curious about how it came to be used in this manner.

[image: WW I poster - "It is far better to face the bullets than to be killed at home by a bomb. Join the army at once & help to stop an air raid. God save the King"]

Only way I could think of how this came to be used, is if they were referring to a "timer" starting or something. As if it means "start at the first moment", or "start at the first chance". Maybe, "first" somehow being implemented as "at once"?

Either way, I cant find any references in regards to how "at once" first became used in this manner.

Comment: Only a thought, so I'll keep to a comment: perhaps the other sense (at once:
All at one time; simultaneously: Everything happened at once.    AHDEL), probably deriving from _at one time_, came to have the additional sense _at this (one) time_, instantly, its accepted other meaning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  concur. I'd guess it originated as a qualifiier or response to a command or request "Do this." - "At once", *viz.* at the same time as you say it. It replaced *presently*, which signified "not in the future, but now, even as I/you  say it."

Comment: Hmm. interesting. Good thought. But how could "at one time" become used as "this (one) time" is the question. What is the "(one)" in time that we are referring to? I don't understand how it could have come from meaning "simultaneously". Which is why I have this question, It just seems it doesn't fit.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think that's right. Note, though, that this is a switch from the historic meaning of _at one time_: _At one time this was all oak forest._ That's an **indefinite** _one_, on the road to becoming _a/an_. The _one_ of _all at one time_, on the other hand, is a **definite**, located, single time in the present or near future in which several propositions converge. Later the _all_ gets dropped and _at one time_ changes to _at once_, which is criterial now.

Comment: okay nice. That makes much more sense. I can definitely see that. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sixth and final definition of *at once* in the OED means "immediately, straightway" and is first documented in William Tyndale's *Expos. & Notes* way back in 1531:

> The apostles were clear-eyed, and espied antichrist at once.

It comes from a meaning of "at one time" and other definitions of *at once* are of things happening at at the same time; or in one heap or body together; or at the same time or simultaneously.

So the "immediately" sense can be similarly thought of as things happening all at the same time, or right now.

> Join the army at once & help to stop an air raid

Or:

> Join the army right now & help to stop an air raid

You read the poster and then join the army all at the same time, or immediately.

Comment: Perfect. :) Thank you. And if you tweeted my question, on the @StackEnglish, thanks as well! That was nice. But All of the answers and comments here are great. I upvoted all I felt were great explanations and put things into perspective, but I choose this as the answer because I feel this answers my question dead on. Thanks Hugo, and everyone else.

Comment: You're welcome. I think [@StackEnglish](https://twitter.com/StackEnglish) is owned by Stack Exchange themselves and is triggered by some mysterious "multi-collider" algorithm thingy.

Answer (score 3):

Since the literal usage means two things happening concurrently, according to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_once), I'd guess that the idiomatic usage assumes that *right now* is one of the concurrent events.